# dockerized testcafe remote browser tests

Tags: macos, docker, testing, testcafe, docker-for-mac

Currently, my project's setup for testing is twofold: as for day-to-day development, I run testcafe through `foreman` on MacOS (to take advantage of my personal `.env` file), and on the CI server (BitBucket), I use testcafe through the `testcafe/testcafe` docker image.

However, not using the same environment during development and CI is not optimal, so I figured using docker(-compose) in both scenarios would be the best way to go. After reading testcafe [issue 1880](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1880) and [PR 2574](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/pull/2574), I figured my command for development should be something like:

```
docker run -v /Users/bert/Development/m4e/ui_factory/test/tests:/test -p 1337:1337 -p 1338:1338 -it testcafe/testcafe -- remote /test --hostname localhost
```

but I seem unable to connect Safari to http://localhost:1337 in this case:

> Safari can't open the page "172.17.0.2:1337/browser/connect/ryD70k" because Safari can't connect to the server "172.17.0.2"

Anyone has an idea on how to tackle this?

Comment: Have you tried launching with --net=host (for docker compose: `network_mode: host`) and use localhost instead 172... docker ip?

Comment: @mulg0r This doesn't seem to work, probably because docker is running inside a virtual machine on MacOS. With the `--net=host` option, testcafe is echoing `Connect URL: http://192.168.65.3:1337/browser/connect`, which is equally unreachable from my local Safari. I guess I'll need some construct with `host.docker.internal`, but not sure exactly how.

Comment: Mmm... maybe if you try with a proxy in VM like `haproxy`. I don't know, sorry, never worked with VM in MAC. Good luck

Comment: Just to clarify: I don't use virtual machines as such, I just use the standard Docker for Mac, which relies on the xhyve hypervisor. In my limited understanding, this is a kind of VM...

Comment: @bertbruynooghe May I know, After you generated the connection URL, do you copy and paste the URL to the browser manually? or is there any automated way of doing it?

Comment: @SashikaWijesinghe Sorry, I don't know anymore. The project I used it for is in a former employer's repository, where I don't have any access anymore...

Answer (score 2):

Please delete unnecessary " -- " in the following record:

*testcafe/testcafe -- remote*

Here is a help topic, which describes how to use TestCafe Docker Image:

[Using TestCafe Docker Image](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/using-testcafe-docker-image.html)

Comment: I agree the `--` is probably obsolete; I just wanted to ensure the testcafe arguments were not inadvertently used as docker arguments.You're very welcome to point me to some explanation on how Docker distinguishes between docker and cmd arguments...

Comment: I agree that the best location for these kind of problems up to now is the link you provided. However, it is incomplete (to say the least) as the issues and the PR I posted in the question prove.

Answer (score 2):

As @Marion pointed out: the culprit is the `--` in the command. I used it to ensure 
the arguments of the command were clearly separated from the docker arguments.
This is not simply 'unnecessary', it is simply wrong.